# Triggering Jenkins job from Appcenter

Tags: jenkins, triggers, visual-studio-app-center

I have hosted Jenkins on google cloud server, To reach Jenkins google generated randomly IP address (for example is) **11.11.12.133**
I also have one build job created in Jenkins  and generated trigger link  to trigger job  remotely. trigger link is like  **11.11.12.133/buildByToken/build?token=token-123&job=sample_build_job** when I am making post request on this link build is triggering successfully.

We also build mobile application and distributing app versions on Appcenter. I want that On every new app versions that will be  distributing on Appcenter, automatically triggered my Jenkins build job. Fortunately Appcenter has option to make post request on specific url with Webhook I tried to  use this url **11.11.12.133/buildByToken/build?token=token-123&job=sample_build_job**  but Appcenter has url validation on integers,  I cant paste **11.11.12.133** I have too paste **11.ab.11.12.133** for example to validate url. I tried to mask url, but it didn't work, I passed first validation in front but when  Appcenter tried to make request on that url there was same error. I also had conversation with Google's related team and they said that ip is randomly generating and I can't change directly url. I also talked to Appcenter and they said that they will discuss to change url validation feature but not in present.

Guys, What I can do?  honestly I had automation test job on Jenkins  and I want that when new app version will be released on Appcenter job triggered automatically